# vue 3 run function and await data before other functions are loaded on app start up

Tags: pouchdb, vuejs3

I'm looking for a good way to load data before my other external functions get loaded. In my case I have a useToken() function with a const token = ref('') I populate the ref with a token  from pouchdb database await token.value = 'bla bla token' .

I have this other function useApi() function that requires the token ref to be be sent in axios header requests.

Basically useToken() would get called in app.vue app startup via Async await.

useApi() would get called after when I try to access my api services.

I have tried app.vue

```
<template>
<suspense><ion-router-outlet />
</suspense> 
</template>
<script>
aysnc setup(){
 await useToken();
}

    </script>

I have also tried 

<template>
<ion-router-outlet />

</template>
<script> setup(){
 onBeforeMount(async () => {
      await initToken();
    });
}
</script>
```

I am migrating from using vuex persistent state which works great. But I thought since I'm using pouchdb and couchdb and with vue 3 new composition api I may as well just use pouchdb to store my local goods.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured my problem I needed to move token outside of useToken() for it to work. I believe this makes the ref global as in it runs once. Putting the ref inside the function creates a new instance of the ref

const token = ref("");
export function useToken () {

```
return{token}
}
```

in app.vue

```
setup(){
 (async () => {
      const test = await initToken();
      console.log("%ctoken inittoken", "font-size: 15px;color:yellow", test);
    })();

      console.log("%ctoken ", "font-size: 15px;color:yellow", token);

}
```